# How to declare/implement array of certain type inside a class (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm trying to implement a new class which suppose to have an array like so:

```
class myclass { 
    OtherClass<something1, something2>* array;  
   ....   
}
```

I want my c'dor to create myclass with an array of size=k of OtherClass.
How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
#include <vector>

class myclass
{
    std::vector<OtherClass<something1, something2>> array;

public:
    explicit myclass(std::size_t n) : array(n) { }
};
```

Comment: is there a way to do so without using vector?

Comment: Good to know _some_ people use `explicit` ;)

Comment: @BobSacamano: Yes, but it requires a lot more effort for zero gain.

Comment: @BobSacamano if you don't want to use a vector then use `std::array`.

Comment: @BobSacamano: If you have to ask, then no. Vector is what you want, trust me, I'm a fish.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use an array, you should have something like this (not recommended):

```
class myclass {
    OtherClass<Something1, Something2>* ptr_to;
public:
    myclass(std::size_t sz): ptr_to(new OtherClass<Something1, Something2>[sz]) {}
    ~myclass(){ delete[] ptr_to; }
};
```

This poses additional problems: move semantics are not very intuitive for types with pointers inside them. A better suggestion would be to use vector, as Kerrek pointed out above.